# How to add new PHP version to WAMP

Tags: windows-7, php, apache-http-server, wamp

I'm trying to install PHP 5.3.8 to work with WAMP (Windows).

I downloaded it from the PHP website, copied it in the bin folder, and added this line to wampmanager.ini:

```
Type: item; Caption: "5.3.8"; Action: multi; Actions:switchPhp5.3.8;
```

and:

```
[switchPhp5.3.8]
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
Action: run; FileName: "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/php-win.exe";Parameters: "switchPhpVersion.php 5.3.8";WorkingDir: "c:/wamp/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: run; FileName: "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/php-win.exe";Parameters: "-c . refresh.php";WorkingDir: "c:/wamp/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: run; FileName: "net"; Parameters: "start wampapache"; ShowCmd: hidden; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: resetservices
Action: readconfig;
```

But it doesn't work...

After I edit it and start WAMP, those changes get removed from the ini file.

Comment: Have you tried downloading it from the [WAMP Addon Site](http://www.wampserver.com/en/addons_php.php)? EDIT: Just realised the most recent version on there is  5.3.1, sorry.

Comment: This is not the right place for this question. Everyone should down vote this question. I need 4 more reps...then I will do it. :P :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you install last version of [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

WampServer 2.1a [24/12/10] Includes :

- Apache 2.2.17
- Php 5.3.3
- Mysql 5.1.53 (version 64 bits)
- Mysql **5.5.8** (version **32** bits)
- PhpMyadmin 3.2.0.1
- SQLBuddy 1.3.2

Comment: Alex is trying to get PHP 5.3.8 working. WAMP 2.1a comes with PHP 5.3.3.

Answer (score 51):

I needed a way to manually install PHP 5.4, because there's no PHP 5.4 addon for my WampServer version.

This thread is a bit old but I'll give the procedure here, as it match to the original question.

*I'll take PHP 5.4.13 for my example (currently the most recent 5.4 version)*

1. Download binaries on [php.net](http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.4)
2. Extract all files in a new folder : `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.13/`
3. Copy the `wampserver.conf` from another php folder (like `php/php5.2.8/`) to the new folder
4. Rename `php.ini-development` file to `phpForApache.ini`
5. Done ! Restart WampServer (>Right Mouseclick on trayicon >Exit)

> ℹ️
> If you are adding php version 5.6, you need to copy `php5apache2_4.dll` from other php folder, too, otherwise the wamp server won't start.

> ℹ️
> If you are adding php version 8+, you also need to copy `php8embed.lib`, `php8phpdbg.dll`, `php8ts.dll`, `php-cgi`, `phpdbg` and `php-win` files for wamp server to be able to start.

Comment: Great answer. Just to be clear as it tripped me up, by `Restart WampServer`, it means Right click the tray icon, click exit, then open WAMP again, rather than clicking the `Restart All Services` button.

Comment: Just want to note that the extracted folder says php-5.6.18 and in Php->Version it displays   -5.6.18   Did it make any difference?  Or I need to rename folder to 5.6.18 by removing - ?

Comment: I have wamp2.5 with php5.5, then i tried this solution to install php5.4 but whenever I change php to 5.4, I cant run any project in my local computer. It seems that apache is not running. Tried to manually click apache >> start service, but still no luck

Comment: I am trying to update from php5.5.12 to php7.0.2 for Magento 2  It's not working wamp logo not changing orange color.

Comment: link http://programming-tips.in/php-configure-php-7-on-wamp/

Comment: It's not working. I tried downloading PHP 7.4.19 this way and it's not showing up if I go to Wamp menu > PHP > Version.

Comment: working, I had php 7.3 and installed php 7.2 with your method, thank you

Comment: Added `PHP 8` in `WAMP 3.1.6` following the ninstructions in this answer and I got this error (visible in windows event viewer) when starting apache: `httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure php8_module`.   To fix it, follow this answer to modify `httpd.conf` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64539221

Answer (score 7):

I too needed to [upgrade PHP in WAMP](http://john-dugan.com/upgrade-php-wamp/) recently. There are a handful of steps to properly do so. I covered them all and provided screenshots in the post linked to above.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: It's not working. I did exactly as it said to install PHP 7.4.19 and it doesn't show up in the list of PHP versions in the WAMP menu.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://websanova.com/blog/php/manually-adding-php-versions-to-wamp) is another helpful article about changing the php version in wamp.

A useful detail that is mentioned in the article is to **update the environment variable to point to the new php**, so you can get access to the right php cli.

Comment: This article worked for me with WAMP 3 going from php 7.0.0 to php 7.1.10.